# Faraday's law applied to a coil in an electromagnetic field

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism, telecommunication

According to Faraday's law,
we have the law:
[image]

where "e" is the electromotive force which is equal to the derivative of the phase of the vector "b" through the surface s of the loop divided by the derivative of time, all with a minus in front that makes it negative, what would happen in a practical sense if the formula were positive?

Comment: "*The minus sign in (3) actually prevents a run-away effect where an induced electric current would create a positive feedback on itself resulting in an unstable, ever-growing, electric current that: 1) ..., and 2) violate energy conservation.*" https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/647146 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/639903

Comment: "*If we change the right hand rule convention, we need to change it everywhere in all physics formulas containing cross products and then the sign in the other Maxwell equation would change*" https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/639811

Answer (score 0):

"what would happen in a practical sense if the formula were positive?"

Nothing, except the calculated voltage would have opposite direction than we have used to see in electromagnetic vector field calculations. The minus is a result of our direction conventions for space vector electromagnetic fields, but it has often got some artistic exaggeration when one uses it to underline that the induced voltage tends to cause currents which oppose the change of the magnetic flux.

As separated from the vector fields the minus has no actual meaning, only that artistic thing.

BTW. If it happens that you want to know which kind of world could have induction where a change in magnetic flux tends to cause a current which increases the flux change, I must answer: No idea. Physicists may be able to derive new fundamental laws which are in accordance with that requirement, but that is nothing practical. The Stack Exchange Worldbuilding site surely has members who are able to imagine something qualitatively flashy sounding of it.

Comment: IMHO, changing sign only in one of the two equations (the other one, where a current creates a magnetic field) would violate conservation of energy. [Lenz's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law)

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/647434 "*The minus sign in (3) actually prevents a run-away effect where an induced electric current would create a positive feedback on itself resulting in an unstable, ever-growing, electric current that: 1) would probably destroy your planet, and 2) violate energy conservation. The minus sign in (3) is a consequence of Lenz’s law, which is a good thing, and since in our universe magnetic monopoles don't seem to exist, the absence of the minus sign in (4) causes no harm.*"